# Difference between binding to events in directive HTML and controller JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a bit vague I'm afraid but I am having some problems with an angular build that is pretty complex and I ***THINK*** the problem is arising from how I bind to mouse events so my question (for now) is:

When listening for a mouse event, is there a difference between using
 `<div ng-mouseup="onMouseUp($event)></div>` in the directive HTML and using `angular.element(someElement).bind("mouseup", $scope.onMouseUp)` in the controller JS?

I've set up an example and there seems to be something going on but I don't get what or why. I'm possibly missing something simple here.
In [this first example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rORwPN?editors=101) the code does as I'd expect - click on the text and it changes, release and it swaps back. The events are bound with `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` and this is what I want to get around.

In [the second example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpajPW?editors=101) only `ng-mousedown` is added to the directive HTML and I attempt to bind to the `mouseup` event using `angular.element().bind()` in the controller only once a `mousedown` is registered. This does not seem to work and I'd love to know why.

Thanks in advance (as always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that in the case of ng-mouse-xx directives, the scope is $applied, in order to inform angular that the event handling function might have changed the model, and that the expressions must thus be reevaluated.

Change the code of the onMouseUp function to

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.stateVar = "Click Here";
});
```

Also, it looks like a bad idea to me to bind a new event listener every time the mouse is down. This should be made once and only once.

Comment: This did the job for my example and my larger issue. Regarding the repeated binding thing, I agree it seems a little messy but in this situation I have ```mouseup``` triggering different functions depending on an initial state at ```mousedown``` and it seems simplest to bind to a different method each time based on that state. Do you have specific reasons for not using this approach - resource heavy, unstable etc? I am going to have a dig though and try a few other approaches. Cheers :)

Comment: Every time bind is called, a new event handler is **added** to the element. It doesn't replace the previous ones.

Comment: Ah I see. I have actually managed to get away from that approach after implementing your last suggestion. In theory though, if I was really efficiently unbinding as well, would it still be bad to bind on the fly like this?

Comment: I'd still prefer to have a single listener, doing the right thing based on the state.